# What is full url to POST listings on Flipkart Marketplace Seller APIs?

Tags: api, flipkart-api

I am building a smart inventory Android app to post items by scanning barcode to my flipkart seller account.

I generated tokens but every time I call POST on the REST API using

url= 'https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/skus/SKUID/listings'

I am getting

> Response:500 internal server error

Can any one help me to list an item on flipkart using API, step by step?

Comment: Please elaborate. Show the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide SKUID value instead of SKUID in url and also provide access token as a parameter in postman.